# How bind to an Id in an Angular Material Autocomplete drop-down, but filter by the string representation

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have an Angular Material Autocomplete drop-down with a filter that filters by `CustomerName`.

This was implemented via my returned Customers from my `getAllCustomers()` method. I then do a `loop` through each `Customer` to `push` the `CustomerName` into a new `array`, which essentially becomes my `filteredOptions`.

**My question is: How can I implement this filter with the search on the CustomerName, but have a binding to the Id of each Customer?**

In the `object` that I eventually want to save, I want to save the `Customer.Id` and not the `CustomerName`.

I have tried creating a new `object array`, containing both the `CustomerName` and `Id`, but this does not work with the `filteredOptions` and `filter` method. It seems like the `filter` method only takes an `array` with single values and not `objects`.

Also, I would need to bind this correctly in my `HTML`.

**Here is my basic `fileredOptions` implementation: (Note: I included my `object` `{name: element.CustomerName, id: element.Id}` that I wish to use. This doesn't work as explained. The working method simply pushes `element.CustomerName` into the `array`:**

```
filteredOptions: Observable<string[]>;

constructor(private loadDataService: LoadDataService, private assetDataService: AssetDataService, private router: Router, private toastr: ToastrService) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.getAllCustomers();
}

filter(val: string): string[] {
    return this.customerNameArray.filter(option => option.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) === 0);
}

getAllCustomers() {
  this.loadDataService.getAllCustomers()
  .subscribe(data => {
    this.customerArray = data;
    let thisArray = [];
    this.customerArray.forEach(element => {
      thisArray.push({name: element.CustomerName, id: element.Id});
    });
    this.customerNameArray = thisArray;
    this.filteredOptions = this.myCustomerSearchControl.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      map(val => this.filter(val))
    );
  });
}
```

**Here is my `HTML`:**

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Customer Search" aria-label="Number" matInput [formControl]="myCustomerSearchControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
        <mat-autocomplete autoActiveFirstOption #auto="matAutocomplete">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option">
            {{ option }}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use an object for your options, you will need to modify your filter function and filteredOptions to use the object and not a string array. You will also need to use the displayWith feature of mat-autocomplete to allow the input to work with the object. A stackblitz example is [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rydwm9).

Your code:

```
export class Customer{
    constructor(public CustomerName: string, public Id: number) { }
}

...

filteredOptions: Observable<Customer[]>;

constructor(private loadDataService: LoadDataService, private assetDataService: AssetDataService, private router: Router, private toastr: ToastrService) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.getAllCustomers();
}

filter(val: any) {
    let name = val.CustomerName || val; // val can be Customer or string
    return this.customerNameArray.filter(option => option.CustomerName.toLowerCase().indexOf(name.toLowerCase()) === 0);
}

getAllCustomers() {
    this.loadDataService.getAllCustomers()
    .subscribe(data => {
        this.customerArray = data;
        let thisArray = [];
        this.customerArray.forEach(element => {
            thisArray.push(new Customer(element.CustomerName, element.Id));
        });
        this.customerNameArray = thisArray;
        this.filteredOptions = this.myCustomerSearchControl.valueChanges.pipe(
            startWith(null),
            map(val => this.filter(val))
        );
    });
}

displayCustomer(cust: Customer) {
    return cust ? cust.CustomerName : '';
}
```

HTML:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Customer Search" aria-label="Number" matInput [formControl]="myCustomerSearchControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
        <mat-autocomplete autoActiveFirstOption #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayCustomer">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option">
            {{ option.CustomerName }}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Hi Tranter, thank you for the answer. i think this is exactly what I am looking for, however, I am sitting with an issue where `displayCustomer` is called before my data has returned. How can I call this correctly after my data has returned?

Comment: Can you modify the stackblitz example to generate the problem you are having and share it? I am not having that problem.